# finding MLE for Epsilon skew exponential distrbiution

Tags: r

I am running the following R code to find the MLE of the Epsilon Skew exponential distribution:

[image]

but I have the following errors along with many warnings. I have searched thoroughly but have found no helpful answers.

> Error in fn(par, ...) : argument "sig" is missing, with no default
>
> Warning messages:
>
> 1: In nlminb(start = c(1, 2, 0.5, 2), objective = fESEP1,  ... :
>     NA/NaN function evaluation
>
> 2: In nlminb(start = c(1, 2, 0.5, 2), objective = fESEP1,  ... :

Here is my program

```
x <- c(2,5,3,7,3,2,0,2)
fESEP<- function(theta){
   th<-theta[1]
   sig<-theta[2]
   eps<-theta[3]
   alp<-theta[4]

   a = log(gamma(1+1/alp))
   b = ((1+eps)*sig*sqrt(2))^alp
   c = ((1-eps)*sig*sqrt(2))^alp
   d = log (sig)
   y1= (x-th)^alp
   y2= (th-x)^alp
   ans <- a + d + sum(y1/b)*ifelse(y2 < 0 ,1,0) +
          a + d + sum(y2/c)*ifelse( y1>= 0 ,1,0)
return(ans)
} 

optim(c(3,2,0.5, 1), fESEP, hessian=TRUE)
nlminb(start=c(1,2,0.5, 2), objective = fESEP,
       control=list(abs.tol = 0.00001,iter.max=100,trace=TRUE))
```

Comment: I tried to clean up your formatting but have no experience with that distribution and would need to see a reference in order to check the accuracy of the code. (Seems like a pretty skimpy dataset for estimating a distributional configuration with 4 parameters.)

Comment: the distribution is

Comment: The dataset that I provide is just as an example. If you need the  dataset, I can send it though email.I need your help guys.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to post this as an answer for now, even though it might better be a comment, so I can have the luxury of formatting.

When I run `optim()` I get

> Error in optim(c(3, 2, 0.5, 1), fESEP, hessian = TRUE) : 
>     objective function in optim evaluates to length 8 not 1

which is an obvious red flag that there's something wrong with your objective function. There's a problem with your last statement:

```
ans <- a + d + sum(y1/b)*ifelse(y2 < 0 ,1,0) +
       a + d + sum(y2/c)*ifelse( y1>= 0 ,1,0)
```

I'm *guessing* that this should be something like

```
ans <- a + d + sum(y1/b*as.numeric(y2<0)) +
       a + d + sum(y2/c*as.numeric(y1>=0))
```

i.e. the `sum()` should be around the entire vector. Actually, though, I think that's probably still wrong: something like

```
ans <- a + d + sum(abs(x-th)^alp)/((1+sign(x-th)*eps)*sig*sqrt(2))^alp)
```

seems more plausible.

But we really can't answer this very well without a link to the information you are using to define the epsilon skew exponential distribution ...

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/g9lcsrg0z2d06me/ESEP.PNG?dl=0
The link to the definition of the distribution. Thank you so much.